# Unable to receive response from the servlet

Tags: android, jsp, servlets

I need to retrieve the control back to Jsp with a response for the request i fired earlier. 
but the problem i am facing is i am not able to get the response in the jsp.

I have gone through few post and tried few suggestion but none seems to work for me. Please, point out where is my mistake.

Below is my try:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("IN form doGet");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        String selectedClass = request.getParameter("key");
        log.info(selectedClass);
        String[] section = null;
        DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler();
        dbhandler.makeConnection();
        if (true == dbhandler.verifyConnection()) {
            section = dbhandler.getSection(selectedClass);
        }
        for (String str : section) {
            log.info(str);
        }
        Logger log;
        if (null != section) {
            request.setAttribute(Appconstants.Section, section);
        }
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.sendRedirect("/ReportFetcher/WebContent/FirstJSP.jsp");
//      RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/First.jsp");
//      view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

and below is jsp part:

```
function funcOnChange() {
    var index = document.detail.Class.selectedIndex;
    var valueSelected = document.detail.Class.options[index].value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        // Check to see if this state change was "request complete", and
        // there was no server error (404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc)
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            var substring=xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert("Alert Dialog! Gaurav");
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 404){
            alert("404 error");
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 500){
            alert("500 error");
        }

    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/FormHandler?key='+encodeURIComponent(valueSelected), true);
    xhr.send(null);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve and what the problem is, but what's the point, in the servlet, to retrieve information from the database and store it in a request attribute, if all you're doing after is send a redirect to another location?

Comment: Actually i need to make two drop down, such that second drop down items are dependent on the first drop down selection. That is why i need to perform DB operation for getting the elements. So, here i am sending a request on onChange of first dropdown and performing DB operation and getting the result back. Now what i want is to send this result back to my jsp and activate the second. but i am unable to send the result.

Comment: A redirect to FirstJSP.jsp tells the browser to send a new request to FirstJSP.jsp. So all you have stored in the attributes of the first request is lost when the second request is handled by the JSP. You want a forward, not a redirect.

Comment: are you sure that your post the jsp part?.. it is javascript?!

Comment: @JBNizet I also tried to forward the request, but that was also not working. The code commented just below sendRedirect() was for forwarding the request.

Comment: @zennon I am using ajax

Comment: @KanishkaGupta: don't try random things to fix your problem. Analyze the problem, read the documentation of the classes and methods you use, use a debugger, add traces to the code. If your only analysis of the problem is "that was also not working", then that's the main problem. You need to be able to say exactly what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead. "It doesn't work" is not helpful at all.

Comment: @JBNizet I completely buy your point, but how a beginner will know what will solve his/her problem, One should have an idea on what to research, So that results would be helpful. Here i am looking for that idea only. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: As I said. Before trying to find how to solve the problem. Try to find, and tell, what the problem is. This is done by adding traces in the code, use a debugger at server side, use the browser dev tools to see the requests that are sent, and the responses that are received, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing everything right and as suggested above also you should need to forward the request instead of redirecting the request.

Point where you are going wrong is you are making an object of XMLHttpRequest and referencing it by using a variable `xhr` while making request, but when you are taking care of response at that time you are checking the status of variable `xmlhttp` , So what you need to do is to replace the variable `xmlhttp` with `xhr`.

If you face any problem, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Onchange of your first drop down make an ajax request to your db.thats what you have already done.
So now you need to write response received in your jsp so it actually populates the second drop down.

For the servlet to respond back you need to use the response object and use the print methods to write the response.

Heres a clue how to generate a option in a drop down dynamically

Use the document.getElementById(yourselecttagid);
And to the above returned tag use the appendChild method to add the options to it..

Okay now that servlet returns the response use the responseText and show it whereever you wantto...in your jsp using the scriplet
Like this

Answer (score 1):

use RequestDispatcher to include or forward your responses and requests. It will be easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably misunderstood the meaning of response.sendDirect method.  That method will

> set the appropriate headers and content body to redirect the client to a different URL.

See for details in SRV.5.4.

So when you involve that method the response is settled and when the client (brower)receives the response it redirect to the URL you set.And what the jsp will receive is a fresh new  request from the brower.